# need guidance on node.js multilingual presentation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am new to node (v0.10) stack. 
I am trying to achieve the following:

I have (hopefully) multilingual articles in the latest MongoDB such as:

```
_id
...more fields...
text: [
{lang: 'en', title: 'some title', body: 'body', slug: 'slug'},
....
]
```

Everytime I display an article in specific language I query as follows:

```
var query = Model.findOne({'text.slug': slug});
query.exec(function(err, doc){
async.each(doc.text, function(item, callback){
    if (item.lang == articleLang) {
        //populate the article to display
    }
});

res.render('view', {post:articleToDisplay});
});
```

Slug is unique for each language!
The problem I have is that mongo will return the whole doc with all subdocs and not just the subdoc I searched for. Now I have to choose to iterate over all subdocs and display the appropriate one on client side or use async.each on the server to get the subdoc I need and only send to the views that one. I am doing it with async on the server. Is that OK? Also async iterates asynchronously but node still waits for the whole loop to finish and then renders the view. Am I missing anything thinking that the user is actually blocked until the async.each finishes? I am still trying to wrap my head around this asynchronous execution. Is there a way I can possibly improve how I manage this code? It seems to be quite standard procedure with subdocs!

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to make use of the `aggregation pipeline`. Using a simple `findOne()` would not be of help,
 since you would then have to redact sub documents in your code rather than allowing mongodb to do it. `find()` and `findOne()` return the whole document when
 a document matches the search criteria.

In the aggregation pipleline you could use the `$unwind` and `$match` operators to achieve this.

```
$unwind:
```

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a
>   document for each element. Each output document is the input document
>   with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

First unwind the document based on the `text` values array.

```
$match:
```

> Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the
>   specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.

Then use the `$match` operator to match the appropriate documents.

```
db.Model.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$text"},
{$match:{"text.slug":slug,"text.lang":articleLang}}
])
```

Doing this would return you only one document with its `text` field containing only one object. such as: (**Note** that the `text` field in the output is not an array)

```
{ "_id" : ... ,.., "text" : { "slug" : "slug", "lang" : "en" ,...} }
```

Comment: Thanks!. If you could answer my question whether the async.each is blocking the app untill all options are iterated and that would constitute accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, it still means you are iterating over all the array items asynchronously rather than sequentially. http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice - for better understanding of how the async works. the async.each().. would still execute asynchronously.But you would get your control back only when all the tasks are completed, i.e all the individual text fields are iterated, and that is when you are rendering your view. Rather, you could set some variable to identify that your match has been found and then call the final callback or exit by stopping all the other tasks.

Comment: @sunlover:tag for the above response.